# LNAI conference accepting papers as accompanying proceedings

Tags: conference, lecture-notes, proceedings

I have submitted an article in a conference which publishes its proceedings in LNAI/LNCS series. However, in the conference website we can see the following text :

> Proceedings with accepted papers are expected to be published in the LNAI/LNCS series (Springer-Verlag), and distributed at the conference.
>   Besides, papers, that according to the evaluation of the referees, are not suitable for the LNAI but that have some merits will be published in accompanying proceedings and scheduled in the conference program.

This statement is confusing to me, especially the second part, which specifies that papers that have some merits will be published in accompanying proceedings and scheduled in the conference program.

Today, as i'm writing this, my paper was accepted for publication at the downloadable (with ISBN) proceedings, and due to corona virus, the conference is cancelled.

My question here, is my publication have the same value as regularly accepted paper.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idealistic answer would be "It is the contribution that matters, not where it is published." But, of course, it is a thing to worry in our academic world. Usually, LNAI/LNCS proceedings paper would be given more weightage (at least perception-wise) than the papers published in some unknown publishers with ISBN.

It seems that the conference has two kinds of acceptance: accept for LNAI, accept for ISBN. Based on the quality judgement by the conference panel and the reviewers, the paper is weighted to be published in either LNAI or ISBN proc. What my guess is that the papers which are of good quality (i.e. contribution is significant) would go for LNAI. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Coder for your answer, indeed the LNAI/LNCS is better, however, i could only find the LNAI proceedings of that conference for the previous years. i didn't find any (ISBN) proceeding. This is why i find it confusing, maybe all proceedings are placed in LNAI !?

Comment: Conferences do update themselves. May be they have a limit on number of papers that they can submit to LNAI. It could be a condition from Springer.